# how to run htmlunit program

Tags: java, web-scraping, htmlunit

This is the code. I am trying to use htmlunit for webscraping. this one is just "hello world" kind of program. I am not able to execute it.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;

import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.FailingHttpStatusCodeException;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.Page;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage;

public class test1 {

public static void main() throws FailingHttpStatusCodeException, 
         MalformedURLException, IOException {
    WebClient abc=new WebClient();
    HtmlPage page =abc.getPage("http://google.com");
    String a= page.asText();
    System.out.print(a);
    }
}
```

[image: when i try to run this, it shows these options. Don't know which ones to select?]

Comment: Assertionviolatedexception-org.apache.bcel.verifier.exc
Constants-org.apache.xerces.impl
Recompile-org.apache.regexp
Class2html-org.apche.bcel.util
And some other 15 options.

Comment: It's asking you what you actually want to run--if you want to run *your* program, choose *yours*. You might want to start off by making sure you actually know how to use your IDE, *then* start writing more-complicated programs.

Comment: i want to run my program. I selected run as java application. I think it should have executed but instead it shows this..

Comment: *I* know what you want to run. You need to tell *it* what to run. We can't see over your shoulder, we don't know what all is on your classpath, etc. See if your class is in there.

Answer (score 0):

run your web application first then run this class as Junit Test